# SQL Server Multiple File Backups - AWS EC2 Disk I/O Cap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sql-server, amazon-ebs

Running a 1 TB SQL Server database on an AWS EC2 C5.4xl server (16 vCPU / 32 GB).
A full backup is starting to approach 3 hours so I figured I should look into multiple file backups. I expected to do some experimenting with EBS sizes, types, and numbers but quickly found that they all give me the same results.

Using Windows Resource Monitor, when running a SQL Server backup I see around 140,000 B/sec reads from the data file and an aggregate of 130 - 135,000 B/sec writes to the backup files/drives. Doesn't seem to matter what I change, I always hit the same numbers. 2 files, 4 files, IOPs drives, throughput drives, doesn't matter.

I finally figured that maybe it is my data drive slowing it all down. You can only write as fast as you're reading, right? So I upgraded it to an IOPS drive and doubled it from 3000 to 6000 IOPS. No change. Still caps at 140 MB/sec read...

Am I just fighting a hard and fast AWS limit here? I've tried this test on multiple machines of several sizes and hit that same (approx) 270 MB/sec limit regardless.

Data drive benchmark:

[image: SQL Data Drive (provisioned IOPS 6000)]

Sample of one of the backup drives (1 of 4) benchmark:

[image: SQL backup drive (1 of 4) default IOPS 3072]

Comment: Try posting screenshots of CrystalDiskMark - SQL Server backups aren't a great way to measure storage speed, since you're also measuring target speeds.

Comment: Sure @BrentOzar, I will do that -- just download and run the default tests? 
I'll have something up in an hour or two after some real production workloads wrap up.

Comment: yep, here's how I use it: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/

Answer (score 2):

Your data files are able to read at 260 MB/sec, so here's what I'd try next:

First, run a backup to NUL, like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDb TO DISK='NUL:'
```

That does the read portion of the backup, but without writing it anywhere, so the writes don't slow it down. (Keep in mind that this is indeed a real backup, so if you're doing differential backups, you don't wanna do this, or you want to do it on a database that isn't in production.)

At the end of that backup, you'll see a MB/sec number. That's how fast your backups can run while reading off the storage. You should see it approaching the CrystalDiskMark sequential read throughputs that you're getting.

260 MB/sec isn't great - that's about the limit of a single GP2 volume. You mentioned that you're using a C5.4xl, and the EBS throughput limit on that is 437 MB/sec anyway - you could stripe your data across two GP2 volumes, and then get better (but not 2x better) read throughput. For higher read throughput, you'd need to change instance types. If you consider that, use the EBS Bandwidth and EBS Throughput columns on [ec2instances.info](https://ec2instances.info/).

Now, back to your tests: once you're able to get the backup to nul running at 250-260 MB/sec, now test the writes. Make sure to use backup compression, and write to a backup target on a different EBS volume. Since your C5.4xl has up to 437 MB/sec throughput (assuming you have EBS optimized configured), then you should be able to get around 170MB/sec write throughput to the write volume, but it has to be a different GP2 volume. (If you try writing to the same volume, your throughput will be coming out of the 260MB/sec cap for a single volume.)

Comment: Thanks Brent.
Backup to NUL gets me close to 270 MB/sec from the data volume, as predicted.
Also, Today I Learned (TIL) that backup compression isn't an option with SQL Server web edition.

Your final paragraph has me scratching my head a bit though. All my testing is using different volume(s) for backup destination, but it all just splits that 270 between read (from data volume) and write (to backup volumes). Without changing instance type, I appear to be red-lined.